# Cypress for Electron with Filesystem support

Tags: electron, cypress, ui-automation

I am new to Cypress. I [read here](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2019/09/26/testing-electron-js-applications-using-cypress-alpha-release/) that Cypress has stopped support for Electron. But when I downloaded, still it shows Electron in Web Browser's list.

My Electron app is bundled within binary package build by Electron and there is no web-url to run for, eg. https://something.com. But it is served as file system URL file://some/path.

Should we go with Cypress, or is it worthy to wait if this support is under development?

Answer (score 0):

Cypress doesn't support Electron with File System. I got the response from [Twitter](https://twitter.com/vishnucgupta/status/1301223004538429440)